# Convert null integer to space SQL in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a database where the employment start date and end date is selected, then displayed

The code I have is as such:

```
Concat(WorkExperience.StartYr, ' ',WorkExperience.StartMonth,' to ', 
IsNULL(WorkExperience.EndYr,''), 
IsNULL(WorkExperience.EndMonth,'Current Job '), '--',
WorkExperience.PositionLevel,'(',CompanyTable.CompanyName,')'
) AS 'Employment History'
```

In WorkExperience.StartYr, there are null values. Its datatype is int

My result is this:

```
1990 Jul to 1992 May--Executive(MidEast Bank)
1993 Jan to 0Current Job --Director(Astons System and Maintenance)
1980 Jan to 1982 May--Executive(Huat Heng Construction)
1984 Jun to 1990 Dec--Manager(Good Earth PTE LTD)
1991 Feb to 0Current Job --Senior Management(Huat Heng Construction)
1999 Apr to 0Current Job --Manager(MidEast Bank)
2012 Aug to 0Current Job --Jr Executive(Huat Heng Construction)
```

I would like to get rid of the '0' in rows 2, 5, 6 and 7
to get

`1993 Jan to Current Job --Director(Astons System and Maintenance)`

How can I do so?

Edit: Thank you for the help, the problem is fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Concat(WorkExperience.StartYr, ' ',
       WorkExperience.StartMonth, ' to ', 
       WorkExperience.EndYr, 
       coalesce(WorkExperience.EndMonth, ' Current Job '), '--',
       WorkExperience.PositionLevel,
       '(',CompanyTable.CompanyName, ')'
) AS Employment_History
```

That is, remove the `ISNULL()`.  `CONCAT()` ignores `NULL` values. You *think* you are replacing the `NULL` value with an empty string.  However, the column is a number -- so the result of the `ISNULL()` is converted to a number.  Hence the `0`.

Note that I also changed the name of the column to `Employment_History` so it does not need to be escaped.  As a general rule, only use single quotes for strings and date constants.  Do not use single quotes for column names.  They are easily confused with string constants.

Answer (score 0):

Because of data type precedence, you need to convert `EndYr` before your `ISNULL`.

Or another alternative is to use a second `CONCAT` which will convert for you.

```sql
CONCAT(
    WorkExperience.StartYr,
    ' ',
    WorkExperience.StartMonth,
    ' to ', 
    ISNULL(
        CAST(WorkExperience.EndYr AS varchar(4)) + ' ' + WorkExperience.EndMonth
        ,'Current Job '),
    '--',
    WorkExperience.PositionLevel,
    '(',
    CompanyTable.CompanyName,
    ')'
) AS [Employment History]
```

```sql
CONCAT(
    WorkExperience.StartYr,
    ' ',
    WorkExperience.StartMonth,
    ' to ', 
    ISNULL(
        CONCAT(WorkExperience.EndYr, ' ', WorkExperience.EndMonth)
        ,'Current Job '),
    '--',
    WorkExperience.PositionLevel,
    '(',
    CompanyTable.CompanyName,
    ')'
) AS [Employment History]
```